# Data is not showing on view page in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

Note: It was working on single view page, but once I pass it to User Dashboard it will be showing error.

I was trying to pass user data from database to form table but it was showing error

Here's my code:

```
 public function questionList() {

        $list = new QuestionsModel();

        $data['questionList'] = $list->findAll();

        return view('user/dashboard', $data);
}
```

Note that I had already have my **QuestionsModel** created

Here's my dashboard.php section of the code

```
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>User ID</th>
                            <th>Lists</th>
                            <th>Answered</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                    <?php foreach($questionList as $list) { ?>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $list['user_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $list['list'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $list['answered'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $list['status'] ?></td>

                        </tr>

                        <?php } ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

How can I solve this please?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($data['questionList'] as $list) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $list['user_id'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $list['list'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $list['answered'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $list['status'] ?></td>
</tr>
```

You don't have a key in the foreach loop. By adding $data before accessing $questionList, you are explicitly telling the view to look for the $questionList variable in the $data array that you passed to the view.

Comment: I was getting the same error, $data cant be find: https://ibb.co/89B6Drz

Comment: $data is not accessible in the view

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will works for you :
still face issue add comment so i can help more.

My route :

```
$routes->get('/rules', 'Home::rules');
```

My Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{

    public function rules()
    {   
        $data['test'] = 'ABC';
        return view('pages/rules', $data);
    }
}
```

My View File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <span><?php echo $test; ?></span>
</body>
</html>
```

My Output :

[image]

Comment: This works, on a single page and single controller, but once I use same in the User dashboard that has many data's, it will be failing.